# É correto e ou indicado unir em um projeto Laravel 5.x com os componentes desenvolvidos no Vuejs 2 tudo dentro do mesmo diretório?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, scope

É conhecido que a integração entre Laravel e vue é boa, porem seria indicado utilizar os componentes vue dentro de um projeto laravel? cada vez que a aplicação crescer será mais amarrado um ao outro, o certo não seria separar essas responsabilidades até mesmo utilizando maquinas diferentes para hospedar front e back.

Answer (score 1):

Tudo depende da forma como você ta desenvolvendo. Se for algo de grande porte eu não recomendo usar a estrutura padrão do Laravel + VueJS e sim utilizar o Laravel apenas como API (Backend, JWT, etc) e utilizar o VueJS Puro (+Webpack). Desta forma você pode ter controle 100% da sua aplicação, fazer Load Balance e escalar conforme for necessário. Porem se for algo pequeno, não tem problema utilizar a estrutura já pronta que vem no Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Depende muito do seu cenário mas...

Aplicações `Laravel + Vue` são excelentes, você pode se comunicar com as blades do `Laravel` através das props do `Vue`.

Porém como já foi dito isso unifica `front` e `back`, o que é uma pratica comum e nada assustadora, a propósito se você separar o front e transformar o back em uma `API REST`, sua aplicação será uma [single page application](http://andremenegassi.com.br/blog/index.php/spa-single-page-application-e-restrestful-o-que-e/), o que requer muito estudo e dependendo do cenário não é algo muito recomendável...

Caso seu foco não seja tanto o front o `webpack mix` da conta do recado pois compila javascript puro, ES6 e outras coisas de acordo com sua necessidade, também aborda toda a parte de minificação...

Mas claro dependendo do seu projeto uma single page application é uma boa, geralmente o build inicial é mais longo mas a aplicação fica bem fluída e rápida, dentre vários outros benefícios de `UX`...

Em relação ao balanceamento de carga, isso tudo pode ser configurado no seu servidor ou em `clusters`.